# I want to update my opportunity record 'onclick'

Tags: apex, lightning, lightning-web-components

[image: Opportunity stages along with the substages]

[image: Details page]

Here onclicking the substage the index value changes to that particular stage.I have used 'selectedindex' to get the value of the currentstage.I am planning to use an update record method with the 'selectedindex' value set as the opportunity substage so that it gets updated in the details page of opportunity.
Stages:default
Substages I have added for each opportunity stage

Code I have written:

```
 import { LightningElement, api, wire,track } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import fetchPicklistField from "@salesforce/apex/Pathcontroller.getDependentPicklistValues";
const FIELDS=['Opportunity.Id','Opportunity.StageName','Opportunity.Sub_Stage__c'];


export default class PathComponent_lwc extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @track currentStep;
    @track stageName;
    @track Steps = [];
    @track substage;
    
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS })
    wiredRecord({ error, data }) {
        if (error) {
           console.log('error occured',error);
        } else if (data) {
            this.fetchFieldvalueDependent();
            console.log('data2--->>>', data);
            console.log('substagecurrentfield@>>>>', data.fields.Sub_Stage__c.displayValue);
            this.substage=data.fields.Sub_Stage__c.displayValue;
                }
    }
    

    fetchFieldvalueDependent(){

        fetchPicklistField({ recrdId: this.recordId})
        .then(result => {
            console.log('result --- >>>',result);
            this.Steps = [];
            for(let res of result){
                this.Steps.push(res);
                if(this.substage==res){
                this.currentStep = this.substage;
                console.log('res',res);
                console.log('substage',this.substage);
                }
        }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('error --- >>>',error);
        });
        
    }
    
}

 let FIELDS = {
                Id: recordId,
                Sub_Stage__c: selectedIndex
            }
            console.log('Id>>',recordId);
            const recordInput = {FIELDS};
            console.log('fields>>>',FIELDS);
            updateRecord(recordInput)
            .then(() =>{
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Success!',
                        message: 'Opportunity stage updated successfully',
                        variant: 'success'
                    })
                )
            })
            .catch(error =>{
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error!',
                        message: 'Something went wrong while updating opportunity stage',
                        variant: 'error'
                    })
                )
            })
```

Html:

```
 <template>
    <lightning-progress-indicator current-step={currentStep} type="path" >
         <template for:each={Steps} for:item="step">
             <lightning-progress-step label={step} key={step} value={step} onclick={handleStepFocus} ></lightning-progress-step>
         </template>
    </lightning-progress-indicator>
Index7: {selectedIndex}
</template>
```

I have tried it using updaterecord and called the 'selectedindex' but there isn't any change in the detail page.Can you point any corrections in this?

Comment: Are you saying that what you have tried is not working? If so, please edit your question to add those specifics (e.g., exact error text, what unexpected results are happening).  If you have not yet tried to get your idea to work, then you need to attempt something and then come back and post your code if it is not working. SFSE exists to *help* you, not do work for you. From the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section of Help Center: *"We’re not a place to exchange code or find implementation services."*

Comment: @Moonpie Okay,modified

Comment: are you saying that your progress indicator is working, however, your record opportunity page is not updating to reflect this? or are you using a custom component to display opportunity record data?

Comment: @glls Yes Sir,Exactly the progress indicator is working.I can add more substages or change the stage and substage changes accordingly.But the changes are not reflected in the record details page.Each time I click a substage that substage should be saved in the details page.I have used an updaterecord function for this and called my current substage value stored in 'selectedindex'.